# android asynctask is not executing inside baseadapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have a Baseadapter for a listview, when 1 of the elements inside gets clicked it is  supposed to execute an AsyncTask. The onClick is inside Baseadapter and that works however the async execute is not working here is my baseAdapter

```
public class LocalFeed_CustomView extends BaseAdapter {

    JSONObject names;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater myiflater;

public  LocalFeed_CustomView(){}


    public LocalFeed_CustomView(JSONObject arr,Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        names = arr;
    //    myiflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      //  System.err.println("vv:" + arr);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("localstreams");
            return jaLocalstreams.length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx,"Error: Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return names.length();
        }


    }




    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if(convertView==null) {

                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
            }

                TextView votes= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.votes);

                JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("localstreams");
                final JSONObject jsonObject = jaLocalstreams.getJSONObject(position);
                jsonObject.getInt("id");
   // the click works because the toast message fires
            votes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                      int Stream_ID= jsonObject.getInt("id");
                        SharedPreferences myaccount = ctx.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        int Profile_id=myaccount.getInt("id", 0);
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "click worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // the execute below is not firing off
                      new Add_Votes(Stream_ID,Profile_id).execute();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.getCause();
                    }

                }
            });




            return convertView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;


    }
}
```

As you can see the execute is not working and both of the int values have numbers in them. This is my AsyncTask

```
public class Add_Votes extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url;
    String result="";
    DataOutputStream wr;
    String Stream_URL;
    Activity m;
    int stream_id,profile_id;


    public Add_Votes(int stream_id,int profile_id)
    {
        this.stream_id=stream_id;
        this.profile_id=profile_id;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Stream_URL= m.getResources().getString(R.string.PathUrl)+"/api/addvote";
//this Toast never fires off
   Toast.makeText(m.getApplicationContext(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try{
            url = new URL(Stream_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.connect();

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            String cert="id="+profile_id+"&stream_id="+stream_id;
            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(cert);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            result = sBuilder.toString();
            reader.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {

           Toast.makeText(m.getApplicationContext(),"Voted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(m.getApplicationContext(),"Inconclusive",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Add_Votes is only an AsyncTask there is no activity associated with it. Any suggestions on how I can call an AsyncTask from a baseadapter would be great. It needs to be from a baseadapter because each row has different values depending on the item clicked which then I pass on to the Async Task.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is you are using a variable *Activity m* and you have not initialised it in your AsyncTask. try passing a *context* from your BaseAdapter to AsyncTask.

In Add_Votes :

```
private Context context;

public Add_Votes(Context context ,int stream_id,int profile_id)
{
    this.stream_id=stream_id;
    this.profile_id=profile_id;
    this.context = context;

}



@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Toast.makeText(context,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

In your BaseAdapter:

```
Add_Votes add_Votes = new Add_Votes(ctx,Stream_ID,Profile_id);
add_Votes.execute();
```